# Sliding og _image typoscript

Tags: typo3-9.x

Here is the typoscript for sliding og image. But its is not working on TyYPO3 9.5.15

```
page.meta {

    og:image.stdWrap.typolink {
            parameter.stdWrap {
                cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
                cObject.file {
                  treatIdAsReference = 1
                    import {
                        data = levelfield:-1, og_image, slide
                        if.isFalse.field = og_image
                    }
                    height = 650
                    width = 1200c
                }
            }
            returnLast = url
            forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
        }
        og:image:url.stdWrap.typolink {
            parameter.stdWrap {
                cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
                cObject.file {
                  treatIdAsReference = 1
                    import {
                        data = levelfield:-1, og_image, slide
                        if.isFalse.field = og_image
                    }
                    height = 650
                    width = 1200c
                }
            }
            returnLast = url
            forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
        } 

}
```

What may be the reason. Please help.

Comment: what for is `if.isFalse.field = og_image` ? looks like it disables the access to the slided field

Comment: If I remove if.isFalse.field = og_image it is not working -Bernd Wilke πφ

Comment: what is working if the `if.isFalse` is active? and what is not working at all (the topic of your question)?

Comment: As per the typoscript code, if no og_image added for a page it is not taking the og_image from its nearest root node.

Comment: sliding means: take the date from field of this page or, if empty, from parent page. or, if empty of parent parent page, ... the content is delivered in the field. if you test if the field is false you only get nothing.

Comment: That means I want to remove if.isFalse.field = og_image ?

Comment: I think so. try it and report result

Comment: Nothing happened if I removed if.isFalse.field = og_image. That is it is not taking data from parent if this page is empty.

Comment: is your field enabled to be inherited? maybe you need to declare it as `rootlinefield`. go to the `ADMIN TOOLS` -> `Settings`-> `Configure Installation-Wide Options` -> `[FE]` -> `[FE][addRootLineFields]` and insert the fieldname

Comment: Its working now. Thank you. This settings helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the field as rootlinefield.

Go to the `ADMIN TOOLS` -> `Settings` -> `Configure Installation-Wide Options` -> `[FE]` -> `[FE][addRootLineFields]` and insert the fieldname.